# Kafka connect cluster pulls data and pushes it in other kafka cluster

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to have a cluster of kafka connect brokers which are resposible for pulling data from different sources and pushing it to topics stored in different nodes of the same cluster. Is there any tutorial, which does not use Confluent platform, that explain this?. I want to have, for now, a node(docker container) with kafka connect pulling data from an RSS and pushing it to a topic placed in other kafka node(docker container).

I appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Kafka Connect is not specific to Confluent Platform. Any tutorial that Confluent has will work fine on a vanilla Apache Kafka cluster.

If you want a Kafka Connect connector between two Kafka clusters, you can look at MirrorMaker2.